# module not found error, but i already pip installed the module

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I am coding in Python 3 in Jupyter notebook. I have pip installed beautifulsoup4 in the command prompt, as well as two different ways within my jupyter notebook itself. I have also already restarted the kernel and restarted Jupyter notebook. For some reason, i am still getting a modulenotefound error when I try to import beautifulsoup4 as soup. I am super confused and any help would be much appreciated!

[image: module not found error and proof of pip installation]

Comment: The imported module name is `bs4`, not `beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22no+module+beautifulsoup4%22

Answer (score 1):

make sure to install below library

```
pip install bs4
```

and then please use below import statement

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```